# Replacing linked (recursive) for loops with a more functional approach

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have:

```
for a in range(100):
    for b in range(50):
        my_func(a, b)
```

I can replace that code with:

```
from itertools import product
product(*[range(100), range(50)])
```

But say I have the following:

```
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(i):
        my_func(i, j)
```

How can I perform a similar replacement (assuming this is possible)?

Comment: Why `product(*[range(100), range(50)])` instead of simply `product(range(100), range(50))`?

Comment: @cdlane That works too. However, I tend to be passing `product` its arguments inside of another function. So this approach is less restrictive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to do it with `itertools` but wouldn't a list comprehension or generator expression suffice?

```
gen = ((i, j) for i in range(100) for j in range(i))

for i, j in gen:
    my_func(i, j)
```